# Resizing CollectionViewCell in UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

I have CollectionView in UIView. How to resize CollectionViewCell to 50% of screen width? I want to create 2 columns in CollectionView.

```
class Class_MyUIViewClass: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate 
{
```

Also i have image and label in CollectionViewCell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sizeForItemAt` method of UICollectionView to manage cell size of it

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.width
    return CGSize(width: screenWidth/2, height: yourHeight)
}
```

Also confirms to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

Comment: myfile.swift:49:10: Instance method 'collectionView(collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'collectionView(_:willDisplaySupplementaryView:forElementKind:at:)' of protocol 'UICollectionViewDelegate'

Comment: 'CGSizeMake' is unavailable in Swift

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the desired cell height, conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`:

```
class Class_MyUIViewClass: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
```

and implement `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let desirednumberOfCollumns: CGFloat = 2
    let width = collectionView.frame.width / desirednumberOfCollumns
    return CGSize(width, yourHeight)
}
```

Comment: 'CGSizeMake' is unavailable in Swift :)